# How to store the login data in session storage and retrieve while commenting using node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have built a login API  and added a comment API. login details and comment details are stored in a different table in Postgres DB. while commenting on how to retrieve the logged-in username. is there a need to use the session storage? if yes how to use that?

login

```js
const admin = await loginData.findOne({ where: { email } });
if (admin && (await bcrypt.compare(password, admin.password))) {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    { admin_id: admin._id, email },
    process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
    {
      expiresIn: "365d",
    }
  );

  admin.token = token;
}
```

comment

```js
try {
  const { comment } = req.body;
  const stageComment = await initCommentModel();
  const id = req.params.id;

  // create comment
  await stageComment.create({
    comment: comment,
    stage_id: id,
  });

  return res.send("SUCCESS");
} catch (err) {
  return res.send(err.stack);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well, as i see you use **jwt token** for login so you comment api should verify token token before to do somehting else.

You have to write [middleware in express JS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-jwt-expressjs) to authetheticate and verify if token is present in header or token is valid or not then you can add the login info into req like `req.email = currentloginuser@gmail.com`.

you can store that token into session storage or localstorage on front end side.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have initialized the `username` column in the comment table and retrieved the username from the local storage and store it in the `username` column in the comment table.

Comment: best approche to use user table id to store in column table what if two users have same name or if user update his username which will create issue in future.